# What is the --set-tuner option of fswebcam?

Tags: video, webcam, ffmpeg, video-editor

From `man fswebcam`

```
-t, --tuner <tuner number>
       Set the tuner to use.
```

I cannot figure out what a tuner is.

Can you provide a brief example of command that uses a tuner?

Comment: I believe that this is for use with TV Tuner cards, unfortunately I do not have such a device to test and give a typical command line...

Comment: [Tuner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuner_(radio)). It's a hardware device which receives and separates radio or television signals.